# Javascript for loop array styling (Roman Numerals)

Tags: css

I am trying to get my ordered list to be roman numerals instead of just numbers but am unsure of where the styling should go

```
const names = ["Name1", "Name2"];
        let nLen = names.length;
        let text = "<ol>";
        
        for (let i = 0; i < nLen; i++) 
            {
                text += "<li>" + names[i] + "</li>";
            }
        text += "</ol>";

        document.getElementById("nLoop").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Numerals`

Comment: Please change your tags to CSS, and remove the arrays and loops tag. This because this question is more CSS based.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the [list style](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp) to roman numbers with the CSS property `style-type: upper-roman`

You can include a inline style to your ol tag when you don't use a CSS stylesheet, like so:

```js
const names = ["Name1", "Name2"];
let nLen = names.length;
let text = `<ol style="list-style-type: upper-roman">`;
for (let i = 0; i < nLen; i++) 
{
  text += "<li>" + names[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ol>";
document.getElementById("nLoop").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="nLoop">
  
</div>
```